# Django serializer.is_valid() makes a call to different custom serializer method

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a django test server. i want to POST user data and return Response with 'username' and 'Token' after successfull registration.

In the following view, I also check if request.data['email'] already exists in Users model. To do this check, I implemented a custom function(validate_email) inside UserSerializer class ,but it gives me unexpected results.

I know this code is just a noob implementation all around and it doesnt bother me for now, but **the more important thing for me is to understand WHY** my code is giving these results. I believe a detailed answer will help me understand python so much better.

Here is the View function inside views.py :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def Register(request):
    r={"username": "JohnDoeyy", "password": "Thisisapassword60!", "email": "test@test.com", "age": "50"}
    #r = request.data

    if not (r.get("username") and r.get("password") and r.get("email")):
        return Response("empty fields")
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=r)
    print("debug1")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("debug2")
        if serializer.is_valid() and serializer.validate_email(r.get("email")): #User.objects.filter(email=r.get("email")).exists():
            print("is_valid:", serializer.is_valid())
            try:
                print("debug3 before .save")
                serializer.save()  #This does NOT work.
                print("debug3 after .save")

                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.instance)
                return Response({"user": serializer.validated_data['username'], "token": token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except Exception as e:
                print("debugException" , e)

                return Response(str(e))
        else:
            print("3")
            return Response("fail")
```

Here is the serializer.py  . Possible culprit the validate_email method.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )
        
        return user

    def validate_email(self,givenEmail=str)->bool:
        print("debug validate email1")
        if User.objects.filter(email=givenEmail).exists():
            print("debug validate emailfalse")
            return False
        print("debug validate email - true")
        return True

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        # Tuple of serialized model fields (see link [2])
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name']
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
> debug1
> debug2
> debug validate email1
> debug validate email - true
> debug validate email1
> debug validate email - true
> is_valid: True
> debug3 before .save
> debugException ***'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'***
>
> [11/Feb/2022 15:07:58] "POST /Register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 40
> ```
>
> Server Response to client: "'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'"

It seems like validate_email() is called twice since i see it's outputsare printed twice and also something is trying to access attribute split of some bool (??)

Comment: change `return True` in `validate_email` to `givenEmail` and `-> bool` to `-> str`.
Does it solve the problem?

Comment: yes it works now, but I have no clue as to WHY it works. 

1) from `->bool` to `-> str` has no effect? 

2) `bool( True)` is the same as return `bool("string")` . Both are True. so what the difference? 3) and very important, from the output:

`debug validate email1` 
`debug validate email - true` 
`debug validate email1` 
`debug validate email - true` 

 it seems like 'validate_email()' is executed 2 times?? why is this possible? how do you explain that?

Comment: Read the doc carefully to understand how to use `validate_<filed_name>`, [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation), there are 3 types of validation. i.e., you are using `validate_email` but you did not define `email` field!

Comment: `1, 2`. It is just type hint, which tells function return a bool type ,`bool(True)==bool('string')!=bool('')`, but for email field you need to return a string, this is the reason you get `'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'`.  `3.` I am not sure about what I think about the reason, so it is better that I do not give a possible wrong answer!

Comment: What happens if you remove `serializer.validate_email(r.get("email"))`? 
@Spyros Kappalamda

Comment: @AD 
first, I am not using any built-in validators. i just constructed my own and named it validate_email.
Second,yes i know strings have .strip method, but I dont even know where strip comes from. I dont even want to return string. i want to return bool. wether email already exists in DB or not.
Finally I did remove `serializer.validate_email(r.get("email"))` and the problem persists. This is output.


`debug1
debug2
debug validate email1
debug validate email - true
is_valid: True
debug3 before .save
debugException 'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: @AD  So, with your suggestion we have found that for some reason`validate_email()`  method,  is being executed by `.is_valid()`. 

Could it be that `is_valid()` tries to run some `validate_<filed_name>` at email field and confuses built-in validator with my custom validator? because if i rename my custom method, then it runs everything ok.